# How to submit spark-submit from Apache Airflow

Tags: apache-spark, airflow-scheduler, spark-submit

Can anyone help me how to schedule a spark job in the Apache Airflow,

I am looking for the script please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amogh, you need to perform the following steps :

1. Download and Install Apache Spark on your Airflow servers from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)
2. Configure your freshly installed Spark like the ones on your cluster.
3. Add the bin directory to your PATH environment variable for convenience.
4. Create a Dag within Airflow with a `BashOperator`, which runs either the spark-submit command or a custom shell responsible for that. See [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/bash.html).